# My friend can't run my openGL program on his linux distro

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, ubuntu, debian

I'm programming an opengl application on ubuntu and it's compiling and running fine. But when I send my program (yes the one compiled in release mode) to my friend who I think is running plain debian the program wont work for him. He told me he was missing some libraries. So I'm wondering: If I'm sending him the libraries I'm using (the .so file) to him with the program, will he be able to run it?
I ran lddtree  and here is the output:

```
game => ./game (interpreter => /lib/ld-linux.so.2)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGL.so.1
    libnvidia-tls.so.280.13 => /usr/lib/libnvidia-tls.so.280.13
    libnvidia-glcore.so.280.13 => /usr/lib/libnvidia-glcore.so.280.13
    libXext.so.6 => not found
    librt.so.1 => not found
    libdl.so.2 => not found
libX11.so.6 => not found
libXxf86vm.so.1 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => not found
libm.so.6 => not found
libgcc_s.so.1 => not found
libc.so.6 => not found
libpthread.so.0 => not found
```

(This is the output from my computer, not his)
Thanks.

Comment: How is your friend running graphical *anything* without `libX11`?

Comment: He has the X11 library. The output is libraries used by my openGL application. And how it says "not found" is weird.

Comment: It might be worth checking if the binary was compiled as 32-bit and your friend's machine is 64-bit (or vice versa)...  If the binary is 32-bit, you may only need to install the necessary 32-bit compatibility packages.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little more complicated than  sending  him a binary. You may need to [build a Debian package](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/).

Comment: The same question to you: What about applications like desura where the linux games need to work on many linux distros?

Comment: I am not familiar with them, but I guess they have a package for each Linux distro. Open source ones can use something like config/make to compile on client machines.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're compiling against different versions (like libc for example -- I guarantee he has it, but it probably doesn't match your version).

The best solution is to just send him the source code and have him compile it (assuming all he has to do is type `make`).

Beyond that, you could cross-compile it for his version of Debian, or statically link everything. I'm not sure how to do either of those though.

Comment: Ok, but what about games on desura for example? They run just fine, and probably on many distros?

Answer (score 0):

Building redistributeable binaries for linux is perfectly feasible. It just requires some bit of extra work. Take Blender for an example.

The guys of Listaller created some tools and libraries to aid in the process. I suggest you read their documentation.

http://listaller.tenstral.net/

Unfortunately most of the interesting docs vanished from the internet (why?), but you can still find them in the Wayback Machine. Look for "binreloc" and "Autopackage"

#### Update

Now in your case the canonical solution is to build all required libraries anew (independently from the distribution binaries) and link them with relative paths into. Sorry I can't tell you out of my head the details, because frankly, I don't remember them. I'd first have to go through my notes again, and probably tinker.

If you're looking for inspiration, just look at how Blender does it.